# PHP with input form with text - do a MySQL query when form focus changes

Tags: php, forms

I am looking for some help about how to make input form handling in PHP.

What I need is when a user writes data into a text form (table1), and moves to another text form (like pressing TAB, or selecting with mouse), then it should start and MySQL query to see if such data written at table1 already existing in the matching MySQL table.

My goal is like to do it without pressing submit button. Something like when google checks if an username you want to register already exists.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
$duplicate_data_test ="";

if (focus has moved to another form field - how to check ?) {

$query = "SELECT table1 FROM testdatabase WHERE table1 = "' . (table1 from the form below - how to get data from the this form field without POST?) .'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    $duplicate_data_test = "This data is already found in the database. Choose something else";

 }

} 

echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';

echo '<input type="text" maxlength="30" name="table1">';
echo '<span class="duplicaterror">'. $duplicate_data_test.' </span>';

echo '<input type="text" maxlength="30" name="table2">';

echo '<input type="submit" value="OK">';
echo '</form>';
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you can't make your "focus has moved to another form field - check" with php, you have to do it with js...

Comment: it is possible with jquery ajax.

Comment: Julo0sS, ShiguriAnemone' : thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do your "interface" check with php. 
Your "focus has moved to another form field" has to be done with javascript.

First,  Build your form with html like this

```
<form name="testForm" action="postForm.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <label>INPUT 1 : </label>
    <input type="text" id="in1" value="" name="input1" />
    <label>INPUT 2 : </label>
    <input type="text" id="in2" value="" name="input2" />
    <div style="color:red;font-weight:bold;" id="error"></div>
    <button id="submitButton">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Then make your checks when user clicks on submit button with javascript/jquery & ajax (prevent event form posting) like this :

```
$(document).on('click','#submitButton',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($.trim($('#in1').val()) == ''){
        //input 1 is empty
        $("#error").html('INPUT ONE IS EMPTY');
    }//....continue checks
```

Finally, if your checks are good, then post your form

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

and if your checks are not good then display user a message!

```
$("#error").html("MESSAGE!");
```

I made you a little example on how to do it (it's not the best way to do it but it's just an example) on jsfiddle, check this link : http://jsfiddle.net/9ayo89jt/2/

hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Julo0sS!

Answer (score 1):

checking if something exists will need an AJAX call

put the query that checks the database in a separate php file and call it with AJAX

---

to submit once all input fields are filled, you will need to use javascript .. check if field 1,2,3,..etc. are not empty .. `formName.submit()`

this is a bad approach in my opinion